# Extjs controller: panel control selector overrides child's selectors

Tags: extjs

I have a panel and a grid on this panel. Both of them have a button with  `itemId=remove`
Also have two controllers with controls like:

```
    'panel_alias      #remove' : {
        click : someAction ...

    'inner_grid_alias #remove' : {
        click : anotherAction ...
```

But, when i click on grid "remove" button, "someAction" are called.

Set a different `itemId` for buttons is not a solution, because controls builds dynamically.

Comment: are you sure you are using the alias and not just `panel`, because `grid` / `gridpanel` inherits from `panel` thus meets the criteria

Comment: sure. it's look like 'news_card' and 'news_tags_list' in my case

Comment: so if you enter `console.log(Ext.ComponentQuery.query('panel_alias #remove'));` the grid is in the array too?

Comment: yes. finaly i change the itemId of grid button and everything works fine, but it's very strange